# Using React-hook-form and I can't change the value of posts whether it is published or not

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

Now, I am working on the project creating a blog like site and I am facing the problem that I can't change the value whether it is published by using checkbox and react-hook-form.

It workded a weeks ago so I am thinking this is due to the update of react-hook-form but I don't know how to solve it.

I am assuming that the code below is the part to be changed.

publish is a checkbox and when checked and submitted the value of post changed to published and turned to be visible. but corrently I can't turn it to be published. It stays false which means it is not published even if it's checked.

```
<fieldset>
  <input className={styles.checkbox} name="published" type="checkbox" ref={register} />
  <label>Published</label>
</fieldset>

<button type="submit" className="btn-green" disabled={!isDirty || !isValid}>
  Save Changes
</button>
```

this part works fine.
{!isDirty || !isValid}

I hope some kind people will help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is similar to your last question - you need to modify the usage of `register` to support v7:

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" {...register("published")} />
  <label>Published</label>
</fieldset>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Checkbox v7]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, and yes. I surely have to read docs of react-hook-form. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I’m glad I could help! The docs also have a very good migration guide describing the breaking changes when switching from v6 to v7. https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I think I understand the change this time.